# loop through nested objects with javascript

Tags: javascript, loops, object, foreach

i' got this code and want to show all images with the foreach() function.

```
var btx = [];
btx["main"] = {};
btx["main"]["us-001"] = {src: "hxxps://domain.com/kus-001.jpg", width: "128" , height: "256"};
btx["main"]["us-002"] = {src: "hxxps://domain.com/kus-002.jpg", width: "128" , height: "256"};
```

thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
for (var key in btx["main"]) {
    console.log (btx["main"][key]["src"])
}
```